# Como almacenar todos los datos de un SELECT en una variable y que se guarden todos los datos y no solo el último

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

Me gustaría saber como puedo guardar todos los resultados que arroja un SELECT en una variable, ya que solo me guarda el último dato.
Lo que he hecho es lo siguiente:

```
<?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM cookies_grupos WHERE usuario = '".$usuario."'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $gruposcookies = $mostrar['grupo'];
  $sql="SELECT * FROM publicaciones WHERE nombre = '".$autor."' AND grupo LIKE '%".$gruposcookies."%' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1"; echo $gruposcookies;}
   $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
   if($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
     $publicacion = $mostrar['publicacion'];}
```

El primer SELECT obtiene varios datos que se guardan en una variable llamada $gruposcookies. Después hay otro SELECT que selecciona los datos que tengan una columna cuyo valor este contenido en la variable $gruposcookies. Posteriormente imprimo la variable $gruposcookies y me imprime lo siguiente: JavaProgramación(general)Futbol. Es decir que el SELECT obtendría los datos cuya columna sea, Java, programación(general) o Futbol. Pero realmente, solo obtiene los datos cuya columna sea igual a Futbol, es decir, únicamente el ultimo valor. No se como arreglarlo. SI alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería.

Comment: Estas usando una variable normal, y al usar el signo de asignacion `=` se sobre escribe, conoces el tipo de variable Array???

Comment: @Arcanis -The Omnipotente Pues no le conozco. ¿Tú crees que con el me funcionará? Investigaré y probaré. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: claro que si un array es una variable que almacena datos el algo parecido a celdas... y estas seldas van numeradas o asociadas https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php

Comment: Como bien dice @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent, aunque Omnipotente sólo es Dios, lo propio aquí sería guardar los datos en un array. Aparte de eso, puedes obtener los resultados en una sola consulta haciendo `JOIN` entre las tablas `cookies` y `publicaciones`. De esta manera optimizarías bastante tu código, pues no es lo mismo traer `N` resultados en una sola consulta, que lanzar `N` consultas para obtener `N` resultados, ya que esto hace trabajar mucho más a la base de datos, desaprovechando además cuestiones como los índices, que darían más fluidez a las consultas.

Comment: @A.Cedano no me refiero a Dios, https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=106426

Comment: Ya, el atributo Omnipotente sólo corresponde a Dios, a nadie más, @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent.

Comment: @A.Cedano bueno, no soy religioso si quieres podemos conversarlo en una sala de chat, saludos...

Comment: No te preocupes, solamente quise hacer la acotación sin más, tampoco es tema para debatir aquí. Para mí los nombres son importantes, simplemente eso. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchas gracias por tu aportación.